# Generic method that returns the appropriate function to handle an argument of parametrized type

Tags: c#, generics

What I basically want to do is have a method called `GetHandler<T>` that returns `Action<T>`. The C# syntax allows for this but honestly I have no idea how you're supposed to implement a method like that.

I want to return a different function based on what type T is, so my current attempt looks like this:

```
    public override Action<T> GetHandler<T>()
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(MyType))
        {
            return delegate (T t)
            {
                var msg = (MyType)t;
                //do stuff
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This doesn't work because it can't convert `T` to `MyType`. I also can't return `delegate (MyType msg)` because of course it doesn't match the signature.

What would be ideal in this situation is if C# allowed multiple overrides of generic methods where you can specify separate handlers for separate inputs and then a catch-all override that handled everything else. I still have no idea how I'd implement the catch all one though.

So what do you suggest I do to get as close to this functionality as possible? The way I see it, my functions can do next to nothing since T can't be cast to anything useful.

Here's an example use of this mechanism:

We have a class that has a collection of instances that implement the above behavior. This class has a method `SendMessage<T>`. The method goes thought all the contained instances and invokes `GetHandler<T>()` on them, checks if the result is null, and if it isn't it sends the handler the message.

Comment: Can you assume anything on `T`? Why not have it implement an interface that would expose some property or method that would result in the `Func<T>` in a generic way?

Comment: The whole point is to have separate handlers that know how to deal with different types. If I started constraining T to anything, I might as well just have a `GetHandler` that always returned the same function that just handles that super class.

Comment: Can you give an example of usage though? I can't quite see how this is useful so some more examples might help figure out the best approach

Comment: But your other option is to have a lot of `if`'s and `switch`'es which makes your use of generics useless.

Comment: I do agree. If there isn't a cleaner option I might as well just handle `object`s...

Comment: 1) Why do you think you need generics? Why don't you use pure and "simple" polymorphism? If all your messages inherit from, say, `BaseMessageHandler`, and all you need is send a message, you just need a delegate for `BaseMessageHandler`, there is no need for generics. 2) Have you considered using a proper design pattern? I could be wrong, but this seem to be the case of using [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), or even [Chain Of Responsability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).

Comment: What I ended up using (and is probably an objectively superior solution) is `IHandlesMessage<T>` interface so I just need to do `obj is IHandlesMessage<MyMessage>` and then send it out. Very clean. I won't change the question since the answers relate to why I originally asked but this appears to be what I actually wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't you just do something like:

```
private void HelloMessageHandler(      HelloMessage      msg ) { ... }
private void GoodByeMessageHandler(    GoodByeMessage    msg ) { ... }
private void HowYaDoingMessageHandler( HowYaDoingMessage msg ) { ... }
.
.
.
public Action<T> GetHandler<T>()
{
  Type t = typeof(T) ;
  Delegate handler ;

  if      ( t == typeof(HelloMessage)      ) handler = (Action<HelloMessage>)      HelloMessageHandler      ;
  else if ( t == typeof(GoodByeMessage)    ) handler = (Action<GoodByeMessage>)    GoodByeMessageHandler    ;
  else if ( t == typeof(HowYaDoingMessage) ) handler = (Action<HowYaDoingMessage>) HowYaDoingMessageHandler ;
  else
  {
    string message =  string.Format( "Unknown Message Type specified: {0}" , t.FullName ) ;
    throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
  }

  Action<T> instance = (Action<T>) handler ;
  return instance ;
}
```

Seems pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: I had no idea you could cast delegates so liberally. Nice solution.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you need because there is not very much context given. But you can cast your way out:

```
        return delegate (T t)
        {
            var msg = (MyType)(object)t;
            //do stuff
        }
```

The double-cast shuts up the compiler. This is generally to be avoided.

Comment: I'm thinking I like this option. How does it perform?

Comment: The same as before. The up-cast to `object` is free (in the case when T is a ref type).

Comment: I had the same kind of issue with `(bool)T` unconstrained. This delivers the cleanest code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help but have you considered just constraining the generic?

```
public override Action<T> GetHandler<T>()
    where T : SomeType // Constrain to some type/interface
{
    // You can treat T like SomeType here
}
```

This way you can at least treat T as `SomeType` - maybe this is what you were after? If not can you give an example of usage so I can better understand what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What I want to do is have a system where each class that implements this pattern has a `GetHandler` that returns varying functions. Each of those functions need to know how to handle a specific type of message. Then, when dealing with instances of these classes, one can just do `instance.GetHandler<HelloMessage>()(msg)`. In my case I can't just assume a class also implements something like `HandleHello()`.